# Imputing missing/cutover values across multiple columns in a dataframe pt 2

Tags: python, pandas

As a follow-up to my original question, I need to change the way I interpolate missing values in the sample dataframe below. The problem assumes that there will be at least two succeeding months with non-0 values from the month with a 0 value.

```py
    ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5
    A   10      20      0       50      25
    B   15      32      0       0       0
    B   0       0       45      51      60
    C   0       100     0       400     150
```

The logic of interpolation would be as follows:

1. Case A & C: "Month(n) with 0 value = Month(n-1)/(Month(n+2)+Month(n-1)) * Month(n+1)" then change the value in "Month(n+1) = Month(n+1) - Month(n)"
2. Case B: Collapse the two rows to fill in the 0 values across the 5 months

The expected dataframe output would then be:

```py
ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5
A   10      20      17.77   32.23   25
B   15      32      45.00   51.00   60
C   0       100     160.00  240.00  150
```

Comment: what you have you tried so far?

Comment: For column B, it is enough to `df.groupby("ID").sum()`. For columns A & C: It looks like your logic only applies to Month2 and Month3. Correct?

Comment: I've tried df.groupby('ID').sum() and df.groupby('ID').first().interpolate(axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index(), to no avail